# SQL query to join these 3 tables to remove spurious rows - OWNER, TYPE, PERSON

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, database-normalization, natural-join

I'm having some trouble joining these 3 tables.

```
Table1
OWNER     TYPE
O1        T1
O1        T2
O2        T1

Table2
OWNER     PERSON
O1        P1
O1        P2
O2        P1

Table3
TYPE     PERSON
T1       P1
T2       P2
T1       P2
```

I want to do a join on all 3 tables so my output would be:

```
FinalTable
OWNER     TYPE     PERSON
O1        T1       P1
O1        T2       P2
O2        T1       P2
O1        T1       P2
```

I'm basically demonstrating how 5NF removes spurious rows. When I join any 2 combinations of the table I get extra data (which is what I expect).

I'm having difficulty joining the third table though, I've never had to work with joining all 3.

This is my query so far:

```
select r1.*, r2.PERSON from table1 r1, table2 r2, table3 r3
where r1.OWNER = r2.OWNER and r2.PERSON = r3.PERSON
```

My output returns 8 rows and some are duplicated. I've tried playing around with the query but it only increases the rows further.

My query is based on an ORACLE APEX tutorial book I have but it isn't joining 3 tables that are laid out like mine.

How do I join these 3 tables to remove spurious rows that I get after joining 2?

Comment: Is  O1  T2  P1 a valid combination, too?

Comment: Hi Stefan, no it's not. I get it in my results when I join all 3, but it isn't in the original set of data. The original set has 4 rows. My task is to break up the table into each possible combination then demonstrate when adding any 2 together we get the row you specify, but when you add the third table, we get the correct 4 rows returned. (removing any spurious data).

Comment: I think what's happening with my results is called a 'cartesian product'. I need to avoid this, but unsure how.

Comment: Cartesian product - this is what you get when executing: select * from t1, t2, t3.  It will give you 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 rows.

Comment: Ah, I've fixed the problem. I feel stupid now. I'll post my answer below. It occurred to me when I Googled Cartesian Product and understood it a bit better.

Comment: @JamLis Hope it helps

Comment: Please see my answer. For problems with the currently accepted answer, see my comments on it & see my answer. PS "5NF removes spurious rows" doesn't make sense. You seem to be joining the 3 (projections/components?) (back?) to a table that's subject to a JD. Or something like that, because you're not clear. If so, it might or might not be in 5NF, and if you decomposed, it was because it *wasn't* in 5NF. Whatever you're trying to say, you're not saying it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put 1 2 3 to every column name to see which table they were under before.
First 3 Query are your approaches and 1 of the relations is ignored in each. 4th approach all 3 relations are put in.

- where t1.owner1=t2.owner2 AND t1.type1=t3.type3 ignoring t2.person2-t3.person3

  ```
  | owner1 | type1 | owner2 | person2 | type3 | person3 |
  |--------|-------|--------|---------|-------|---------|
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P2 |different ppl
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P1 |different ppl
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P1 |    T2 |      P2 |different ppl
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P2 |    T2 |      P2 |
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P2 |different ppl
  ```
- where t2.owner1=t1.owner2  AND t2.person2=t3.person3 ignoring t1.type1-t3.type3 relation

  ```
  | owner1 | type1 | owner2 | person2 | type3 | person3 |
  |--------|-------|--------|---------|-------|---------|
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |different types
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |different types
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T2 |      P2 |different types
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P2 |    T2 |      P2 |
  ```
- where t3.person2=t2.person3 AND t3.type3=t1.type1 ignoring t1.owner1-t2.owner2 relation

  ```
  | owner1 | type1 | owner2 | person2 | type3 | person3 |
  |--------|-------|--------|---------|-------|---------|
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |different owners
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P2 |    T2 |      P2 |
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |different owners
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |different owners
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  ```
- where r1.owner1 = r2.owner2 and r2.person2 = r3.person3 and r1.type1 = r3.type3 (4 results)

  ```
  | owner1 | type1 | owner2 | person2 | type3 | person3 |
  |--------|-------|--------|---------|-------|---------|
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  |     O1 |    T1 |     O1 |      P2 |    T1 |      P2 |
  |     O1 |    T2 |     O1 |      P2 |    T2 |      P2 |
  |     O2 |    T1 |     O2 |      P1 |    T1 |      P1 |
  ```

  Every row is unique and every type,person and owner are same row-wise.

Unwanted output occured when a relation ignored (for example person.when person2-person3 relation ignored) person2s via table2.owner2 and person3s via table3.type3 will all be added to result as if they are irrelevant fields.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52075d/23

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Much better explanation to my crappy one below, so I've marked this. Take care

Comment: @philipxy 3tables and 3 relations,in where clause there are only 2. it should be 3 since there are 3 relations. Cardinality is there because if M-M relations were represented as additional tables he wouldn't get confused, the answer would be clear, which is the point of the exercise that he is working on i assume. But if you want push harder on the point that cardinality is irrelevant. Yes even if all those fields are not F.Keys in this tiny schema  than yes cardinality is irrelevant. Should i delete the offtopic part,is this your contribution?

Comment: Hi. See my answer. Presumably you can see by what I mention what needn't be mentioned. I don't mean to be cryptic re unintelligibility; I think it is *unavoidably obvious* that your sentences are not clear. As I said I can't tell what you are trying to say, except that you mention certain things that are not necessary. I'm not saying you're not saying something helpful. Things could be said--eg about EQDs/INDs. But FKs, CKs & cardinalities are just not relevant--there do not have to be any FKs or particular CKs or cardinalities or even any example rows *or columns* to answer the question.

Comment: @philipxy better?or should i sprinkle some DBMS concept which are not included in question.

Comment: @philipxy isnt natural join means,simple join aka innerjoin by default or leftjoin or rightjoin what is the point of explicitly stating natural in code ?

Comment: I can't understand your comments or your answer or why you have put any of those queries/wheres in your answer. You don't connect what the asker wants, which is *two relational natural joins because that's what lossless join/decomposition involves*, to your queries or conditions so you don't answer the question. I told you, read my answer. Re relational natural join & SQL natural join you can read about them anywhere. There's no need for me to repeat that. You should also find out about normalization to 5NF. You don't seem to understand the question. I am just repeating myself. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy i already read the concepts you said and read your answers. we need 4 rows, but we are getting more rows instead.7-8 row results are explained,what are those extra rows and why are there. what is needed for desired result. Wishing good luck  and assuming that i haven't read your answers ? be pretentious fine but repeating you do not understand those unless it is answered as you dictate, criticizing all answers and down voting marked answer and, that is just intellectual flashing that no one asked for.you are right there is 0need and necessity for DBMS concepts here irrelevant or not

Comment: Downvote mouseover text: "This answer is not useful". I explained why. My comments are to help you & readers. I explained my good luck/bye: I am repeating myself. (The intermediate join results of 2 of the 3 tables are *irrelevant*, because *a 5NF decomposition to those 3 guarantees that their natural join is the original*. Per my answer.)

Comment: @philipxy thanks for helpful comment about hovering on down vote button.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be losslessly decomposing a table into 3 others as part of getting a 5NF design.

Normalization involves losslessly decomposing a table into projections/components that that *natural join* back to it.

(We say the original satisfied a certain JD (join dependency) characterized by the column sets of the components. If spurious (sub)rows appear from natural joining some components then they are just going to eventually be removed after all the components are natural joined.)

Relational natural join has an SQL natural join syntax. (Assume no nulls or duplicate rows, because relations don't have those.) This gives us back your original table from its components:

```
select *
from table1
natural join table2
natural join table3
```

We can write this using inner join on equality of shared columns:

```
select table1.type, table2.person, table1.owner
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.owner=table2.owner
-- relevant columns are table1.owner, table1.type, table2.person
inner join table3
on table1.type=table3.type
and table2.person=table3.person
-- relevant columns are table1.owner, table1.type, table2.person
```

[An sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8050d/4)

(SQL `distinct` is not needed here. This follows from the fact that the natural joins return rows 1:1 in a certain 1:1 correspondence with those returned by relational equijoin & its expression in SQL via inner join.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I linked 2 of the 3 tables. My working query is below:

```
select r1.*, r2.PERSON from table1 r1, table2 r2, table3 r3 where r1.OWNER = r2.OWNER and r1.TYPE = r3.TYPE and r2.PERSON = r3.PERSON
```

I apologise for wasting the time of the community as this ultimately came down to me being negligent and I didn't fully understand that a link which exists in the tables has to be expressed in the query.

Comment: "a link which exists in the tables" & "has to be expressed in the query" are unintelligible.

Answer (score 1):

Many people would recommend using JOIN ... ON for this.
eg

```
create table t1 as
select 'O1' as owner, 'T1' as type from dual union all
select 'O1', 'T2' from dual union all
select 'O2', 'T1' from dual ;

create table t2 as
select 'O1' as owner, 'P1' as person from dual union all
select 'O1', 'P2' from dual union all
select 'O2', 'P1' from dual ;

create table t3 as
select 'T1' as type, 'P1' as person from dual union all
select 'T2', 'P2' from dual union all
select 'T1', 'P2' from dual ;
```

Query

```
select
  t1.*
, t2.PERSON 
from   t1  
  join t2  on t1.OWNER = t2.OWNER
  join t3  on t2.PERSON = t3.PERSON and t1.type = t3.type
;

-- result
OWNER  TYPE  PERSON  
O2     T1    P1      
O1     T1    P1      
O1     T2    P2      
O1     T1    P2
```

Comment: @philipxy - When this was discussed yesterday, the OP decided to post their own answer.  After that, I have added this, only to say that JOIN ... ON could be used.

Comment: Ok that's why you wrote this post this way but that leaves this a poor answer to the question--my last comment still stands.